# How to Remove Custom Share Buttons from Single page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just add Sharing buttons in WordPress. I want to show it on Posts only but it's showing on Pages also. How can i remove buttons from Pages. This is my Website link http://mycodeskill.com

I used this Code

```
    function mcs_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
    global $post;
    if(is_singular() || is_home()){

        // Get current page URL 
        $crunchifyURL = urlencode(get_permalink());

        // Get current page title
        $crunchifyTitle = str_replace( ' ', '%20', get_the_title());

        // Get Post Thumbnail for pinterest
        $crunchifyThumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

        // Construct sharing URL without using any script
        $twitterURL = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='.$crunchifyTitle.'&amp;url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;via=Crunchify';
        $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$crunchifyURL;
        $googleURL = 'https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$crunchifyURL;
        $linkedInURL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;title='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Based on popular demand added Pinterest too
        $pinterestURL = 'https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.$crunchifyURL.'&amp;media='.$crunchifyThumbnail[0].'&amp;description='.$crunchifyTitle;

        // Add sharing button at the end of page/page content
        $content .= '<div class="mcs-social">';
        $content .= '<h5><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> SHARE <strong>ON</strong></h5> <a class="mcs-link mcs-twitter" href="'. $twitterURL .'" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Twitter</span> </a>';
        $content .= '<a class="mcs-link mcs-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Facebook</span></a>';
        $content .= '<a class="mcs-link mcs-googleplus" href="'.$googleURL.'" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Google+</span></a>';
        $content .= '<a class="mcs-link mcs-linkedin" href="'.$linkedInURL.'" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i> LinkedIn</span></a>';
        $content .= '<a class="mcs-link mcs-pinterest" href="'.$pinterestURL.'" data-pin-custom="true" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pin It</span></a>';
        $content .= '</div>';

        return $content;
    }else{
        // if not a post/page then don't include sharing button
        return $content;
    }
};
add_filter( 'the_content', 'mcs_social_sharing_buttons');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is_singular() returns true also for pages, so replace is_singular() with [is_single()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) to the if statement at the beginning:

```
function mcs_social_sharing_buttons($content) {
global $post;
if(is_single() || is_home()){
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Used [is_singular($post_types)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) with Parameters `$post_types="your post type"`

```
if ( is_single( 'post' ) {
    // Do something
}
```